# jquery autopopulated select Box and table

Tags: jquery

```
 function createDynamicTable(tbody, rows, cols) {
    if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1) return;
    for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
        var trow = $("<tr>");
        for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
            var input = $("<input />");
            $("<td>")
                    .addClass("tableCell")
                    .append(input)
                    .data("col", c)
                    .appendTo(trow);
        }
        trow.appendTo(tbody);
    }
}
```

This script is called on the `on change` event of a select tag, whenever I change the option and generate a table.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect?

Comment: please throw some console errors, html, details..is the question about binding to "onchange" event? or the appending doesn't work?

Comment: actual take one slect tag in html and on this select tag i use jquery and create another select tag.on that created select tag use createdynamictable  jquery . so whever change the second select tag option create multiple table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly but I would certainly try moving

```
var trow
var input
```

outside the for loops, if it won't solve anything else, it would make the function more efficient. also I suspect that because of scoping issues:

```
trow.appendTo
```

won't have trow variable defined when you try to append

**edit:** I've made a [working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ecodic/7/edit) with this working. I don't understand what is the exact problem or question:

**another edit**: If the question is (as I presume) about binding to select box change, I've changed the [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ecodic/7/edit) accordingly .

Comment: actual take one slect tag in html and on this select tag i use jquery and create another select tag.on that created select tag use createdynamictable jquery . so whever change the second select tag option create multiple table

Comment: ok I guess my example jsbin solves the initial problem for you (and the  implantation specifics are for you) , it is customary  here to vote the answer as a solved. to close the question and be a part of the community.

Comment: please check link [link]http://jsbin.com/ecodic/18/edit alert #pid alert function is not call

Comment: I presume this is another question but since you asked the function should be in the right context, when I moved it works alright http://jsbin.com/ecodic/21/edit

Comment: please help me i want make like this..http://www.orthoimplantcompany.com/products/ please give me a demo

Comment: sorry, You'll have to rephrase this as a different question. and connect it here, You'll have to be more specific with the specific problem and question since you don't expect me to build this site for you, don't you?